# Conditional bool check from tuple groups C#

Tags: c#, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I thought it was a simple problem, turned out no so simple at least for me.

I have

```
(bool isEqual, bool duplicateCheckEnabled) group1 = (false, false);
(bool isEqual, bool duplicateCheckEnabled) group2 = (true, true);
(bool isEqual, bool duplicateCheckEnabled) group3 = (true, true);
(bool isEqual, bool duplicateCheckEnabled) group4 = (false, true);
(bool isEqual, bool duplicateCheckEnabled) group5 = (false, false);
```

The values are populated from an external logic. I would each of those tuple property using another object.
For all the groups from `group1` to `group5` that have `duplicateCheckEnabled` as true, I want to check if all the corresponding `isEqual` flags are true. For the given above values, I would only want `group2`, `group3` and `group4` isEqual to be considered (as per `duplicateCheckEnabled` `flag true`), so that the expression evaluates as

```
bool isDuplicate = group2.isEqual && group3.isEqual && group4.isEqual
```

Should I use an array to store only the groups that I want the isEqual comparison to apply?

Comment: Why are you not using an array in the first place? This is an easy job with LINQ.

Comment: I would populate the 5 groups using a different logic, thought it was easier to maintain it separetely, but I get your point. if I have an array of objects with two bool properties and find an easy way of setting it, then yes easier to filter out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this can be done without an array:

```
bool isDuplicate = (!group1.duplicateCheckEnabled || group1.isEqual) &&
                   (!group2.duplicateCheckEnabled || group2.isEqual) &&
                   (!group3.duplicateCheckEnabled || group3.isEqual) &&
                   (!group4.duplicateCheckEnabled || group4.isEqual) &&
                   (!group5.duplicateCheckEnabled || group5.isEqual);
```

You should still put all those values into an array/list, ideally of a custom struct/class.

```
YourCustomStruct[] groups = { ... };
bool isDuplicate = groups.Aggregate(true, (x, y) => x && (!y.DuplicateCheckEnabled || y.IsEqual));
```